# Wake up app from background when wifi conectivity

Tags: ios, wifi, background-process

I need my app to wake up when the phone has wifi conection so it can upload pictures to a server.
I've checked the [background modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) and the closest mode I could choose is voip, but that wouldnt be right. I know that Google Analytics sends the info about the usage of the app while it has wifi connection, even if it's in the background, so there must be a way to do that.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, it is not possible to do so. If you read through the Apple developer's guide, it indicates that only certain functions are available as background tasks, and this isn't one of them. Check out the section "Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks" in the following document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

The following was a similar post:
[iOS app background upload trigger for wifi connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586859/ios-app-background-upload-trigger-for-wifi-connection)

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering can we use `NEHotspotHelper`  to listen when a certain WiFi connected or disconnected?