# iOS app background upload trigger for wifi connection

Tags: ios, upload, background, wifi

I have an app that uploads its captured media to the cloud as its captured: photos, video, audio. HD videos are large and we want the originals stored. Any video over 50mb gives an alert that can be overridden and waits for a wifi connection. It there any way that even if the app is closed or in the background a wifi connection will trigger the upload event similar to Apples update/upload when phone is on wifi and plugged in to power and in sleep mode.

Comment: Nope. There is no way to run your app *without* any user interaction.

Comment: I thought that was the case but wanted to see if anyone had success with work arounds or solutions I had not heard of.